# Eclipse 2021-12 & Aptana Studio 3 Conflict

Tags: java, eclipse, aptana

I installed Eclipse (IDE for PHP Developers Version 2021-12 (4.22.0)) and Aptana Studio 3 (Version 3.6) via Eclipse Marketplace on my new MacBook (macOS Monterey Version 12.1).

Installing eclipse worked fine, but after installing Aptana Studio 3 I got these errors:

An internal error occurred during: "Loading bundle: /Users/myname/eclipse/php-2021-12/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/604/0/.cp/bundles/haml.ruble".
(LoadError) load error: builtin/java/java.util.regex -- java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make java.lang.CharSequence java.util.regex.Matcher.getSubSequence(int,int) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util.regex" to unnamed module @2ec59396

An internal error occurred during: "Loading bundle: /Users/myname/eclipse/php-2021-12/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/604/0/.cp/bundles/rails.ruble".
(LoadError) load error: builtin/java/java.net -- java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make static java.net.URL java.net.URL.fromURI(java.net.URI) throws java.net.MalformedURLException accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.net" to unnamed module @2ec59396

An internal error occurred during: "Loading bundle: /Users/myname/eclipse/php-2021-12/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/604/0/.cp/bundles/rspec.ruble".
(LoadError) load error: builtin/java/java.util.regex -- java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make static java.util.regex.Pattern$CharPredicate java.util.regex.Pattern.ALL() accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util.regex" to unnamed module @2ec59396

I tried to reinstall Eclipse and Aptana multiple times, but these three errors always show up. There seems to be a conflict. Do you have any suggestions how to solve this problem?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Ines

Comment: Some part of Aptana is trying to hack core Java code, recent versions of Java do not allow this anymore.

Comment: Hi Greg, thank you for your fast response. Do you see a solution to run Eclipse with Aptana on my new MacBook or is it not possible?

Comment: I'm not an Aptana expert but their web site talks about Eclipse 4.13 (2019-09) and the site hasn't been updated in 2 years. Only very recent releases of Eclipse work properly on macOS 12 so it doesn't look good to me.

Comment: Hi Greg, I think you are right. I'm gonna look for a suitable alternative. Thank your for answering my question!